# Commits from one pull request showing in a second one

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I'm new to GitHub and I have a problem that commits from a first pull request are showing in a subsequent pull request. That is:

**Pull Request 1 (PR1)**

I see commits:

- pr1sha1
- pr1sha2

**Pull Request 2 (PR2)**

I see commits:

- pr1sha1
- pr1sha2
- pr2sha1

I don't know what happened.

Why do the commits from PR1 also appear in PR2, and how can I fix it?

Comment: When you approve PR1 and merge, the rest should be fine.

Comment: @0andriy if pr1 is merge does the pr1 commits in pr2 will removed also?

Comment: It will be “fixed” during merge. Important step is what I described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be because you either didn't branch at all, or you used the PR1 branch as the starting point for PR2.

One option would be simply to close PR1 and have PR2 merged, or just merge PR1 and then PR2. Either of these options will be fine. In what follows, I assume that for some reason you can't do this and you need to them to be merged as two separate PRs.

To fix, you would interactively rebase on the PR2 branch, and "drop" the commits you don't need.

I assume you are on the branch pr2branch.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~~~~
```

A screen appears with a list of commits like:

```
pick pr2sha1 Commit message pr2sha1
pick pr1sha2 Commit message pr1sha2
pick pr1sha1 Commit message pr1sha1
pick 4dced1f Commit message
```

You should also see instructions underneath in comments. You should read those instructions.

Anyhow, since you want to "drop" the commits relating to PR1, you would change the text to:

```
pick pr2sha1 Commit message pr2sha1
drop pr1sha2 Commit message pr1sha2
drop pr1sha1 Commit message pr1sha1
pick 4dced1f Commit message
```

Then save that, and then update the PR:

```
git push origin pr2branch --force
```

For more on interactive rebasing see e.g. [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History).

To avoid this next time, always do these steps, after you push to raise a PR.

(If the main branch is called master and the new branch for your second PR is new-pr-branch.)

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout -b new-pr-branch
```

(Although some people recommend not using `git pull`, e.g. [here](https://coderwall.com/p/jgn6-q/git-pull-is-evil).)

Comment: @alexharv074 i have tried your solution however this is the result Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Please commit or stash them.

Comment: So, you need to commit or stash your changes. :)

Comment: @alexharv074 thank you very much for your help. It did work.

Comment: That's great. Also, you should mark the question as resolved, see here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work